# Cannot Update Topography Material

Tags: revit-api, autodesk

My Revit file has some topography overrides. There are overrides for the topography type as well.

Now, when I change the material in the topography it does not update in the 3D view.

[image: revit topography overrides]

Is there anything wrong with the override settings? When I completely turn off the overrides for topography it hides the topography completely which I don't want. Please suggest what override should be used.

[image: revit topography materials]

Is there another possible reason why the topography material is not updating even after selecting and picking material from the materials section as seen in the figure - topography materials.

Would appreciate any response. Thanks!